# Objective-C Regex single and double quotes

Tags: objective-c, regex

I'm trying to devise a regex in obj-c to match any of the following jquery-type statements

```
$(body)
$('.body')
$("bo-dy")
```

The problem I'm having is that obj-c seems to fail whenever the subject includes single or double quotes

```
"\\$\\([a-zA-Z0-9_#-\\.'\"]+\\)"
```

From the above...

```
$(test) <- success
$(.d-s3#_t) <- success 
$('test') <- fail
$("test) <- fail
```

bizarrely including the apostrophe vs single quote char means that it does provide a match if a single quote is the first and only occurrence of the character!

```
"\\$\\([a-zA-Z0-9_#-\\.‘'\"]+\\)"

$('test) <- success
$('test') <- fail
```

Does anyone have any insight here? I've tried every escaping tactic I can think of and reduced it to simplistic regexes such as

```
"[_‘'\"]"
```

with the same results. It works fine in other language platforms, so It does seem to be obj-c specific

Comment: If you print the string `"\\$\\([a-zA-Z0-9_#-\\.'\"]+\\)"`, what do you get?

Comment: `\$\([a-zA-Z0-9_#-\.'"]+\)`, if I add the standard start/end delimiters to get `/\$\([a-zA-Z0-9_#-\.'"]+\)/` it works perfectly on other platforms  http://www.switchplane.com/awesome/preg-match-regular-expression-tester

Comment: sorry, better link http://www.switchplane.com/awesome/preg-match-regular-expression-tester/?pattern=%2F%5C%24%5C%28%5Ba-zA-Z0-9_%23-%5C.%27%22%5D%2B%5C%29%2F&subject=%24%28%27test%27%29

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape all double-quotes, for example:

```
[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\"bo-dy\")" ...
```

Single-quotes shouldn't need escaping:

```
[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\('test'\\)" ...
```

Notice above, instead of a capture group I'm escaping `(` `)` to match the parentheses. Here's another quick example; This will match all of your strings:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([$\\-\\(\\w\"'\\.\\)\\\\]*)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive | NSRegularExpressionAllowCommentsAndWhitespace error:&error];
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:searchText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

Result:

```
$(body)
$('.body')
$("bo-dy")
$('test')\n
$(body)
$('.body')
$("bo-dy")
$(test)
$(.d-s3#_t)
$('test')
$("test)
$('test)
$('test')
```